# ReactJs, Typescript protected route with HOC as functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I can't figure out how to build a simple HOC to protect a component, i.e. make sure that the user is logged in before the component renders.

Here is my attempt to build the HOC to protect the component (doesn't work yet).

```js
export default function ProtectedRoute(Component: React.ComponentType) {
  return () => {
    const authUser = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();

    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    if (!authUser) {
      router.push('/login');
      return null;
    }
    return <Component />;
  };
}
```

Here is the component I want to protect.

```js
const AppLayout = ({
  children,
  title = 'This is the default title',
}: Props): React.ReactElement => {
return (
     ...
      <main className="bg-nord-bg2">
        <div className="min-h-screen w-full max-w-screen-xl mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <Alert />
          {children}
        </div>
      </main>
)
}

export default ProtectedRoute(AppLayout);
```

This is how I call the layout component:

```js
function App({ Component, pageProps }: any) {
  return (
        <Layout title="Meno">
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      ) 
}

export default App;
```

This is my error message:  `Argument of type '({ children, title, }: Props) => React.ReactElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{}>'. Type '({ children, title, }: Props) => React.ReactElement' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'. Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible. Property 'title' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'Props'`

Do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 1):

In short, your `AppLayout` doesn't return a `ReactElement` but a `FC` (Functional Component).

I'd recommend this [cheatsheat](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react) for type differences.

---

Here's a working example project that can be found [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/with-typescript-hoc).

**components/AppContext/index.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";
import type { FC, ReactNode } from "react";

type Context = {
  isAuthenticated: Boolean;
  handleAuthentication: () => void;
}

const AppContext = createContext<Context>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  handleAuthentication: () => {},
});

const AppContextProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthentication] = useState(false);

  const handleAuthentication = useCallback(() => {
    setAuthentication((prevState) => !prevState);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        handleAuthentication,
      }}
    >
      {children}
      {isAuthenticated && (
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAuthentication}>
          Log out
        </button>
      )}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export default AppContextProvider;
```

**components/withAuthentication/index.tsx**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAppContext } from "../AppContext";
import type { FC } from "react";

type withAuthenticationFn = (Component: FC) => FC;

const withAuthentication: withAuthenticationFn = (Component) => {
  const Authenticated: FC = (): JSX.Element | null => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAppContext();
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) router.push("/login");
    });

    return isAuthenticated ? <Component /> : null;
  };

  return Authenticated;
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

**pages/_app.tsx**

```
import AppContextProvider from "../components/AppContext";
import type { FC } from "react";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

const App: FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <AppContextProvider>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </AppContextProvider>
);

export default App;
```

**pages/about.tsx**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import withAuthentication from "../components/withAuthentication";
import type { NextPage } from "next";

const AboutPage: NextPage = () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title> About - Next App</title>
    </Head>
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>This is the about page</p>
    <p>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>Go home</a>
      </Link>
    </p>
  </>
);

export default withAuthentication(AboutPage);
```

**pages/index.tsx**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import withAuthentication from "../components/withAuthentication";
import type { NextPage } from "next";

const IndexPage: NextPage = () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title> Dashboard - Next App</title>
    </Head>
    <h1>Hello Next.js </h1>
    <p>
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
    </p>
  </>
);

export default withAuthentication(IndexPage);
```

**pages/login.tsx**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAppContext } from "../components/AppContext";
import type { NextPage } from "next";

const Login: NextPage = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, handleAuthentication } = useAppContext();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) router.push("/");
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title> Login - Next App</title>
      </Head>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAuthentication}>
        Log in
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```